# How do I define a filter query when creating an enrich policy using the Elasticsearch Nest client?

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I'm using the Elasticsearch Nest client to programmatically create an enrich policy as defined [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/put-enrich-policy-api.html). For the enrich policy I'd like to define a query to filter the set of documents used in the enrichment index. This is supported but it looks like the Nest object wants a string instead of a `QueryContainer`. Is there some other way to specify a filter without building a raw string value? This implementation is different from most other parts of the Nest client and feels like a miss. Sample code below.

```
    var request = new Nest.PutEnrichPolicyRequest(policyName)
    {
        Match = new Nest.EnrichPolicy
        {
            Indices = sourceIndex,
            MatchField = matchField,
            EnrichFields = enrichmentFields.ToArray(),
            Query = filter   // Expects a string instead of a QueryContainer
        }
    };

    var result = await _elasticClient.Enrich.PutPolicyAsync(request, ct: cancellationToken);
```